# NSNotificationCenter related crash on iOS 3.2

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, crash, nsnotificationcenter

Our app works fine on iOS 4.2 and 4.3.
However, on iOS 3.2 it crashes at this line

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notificnname" object:nil];
```

The function postNotificationName is available since iOS 2.0.
I am building my app with iOS 4.3 and the target sdk is set as 3.2.
Any ideas what could be causing the crash.

Thanks.

Comment: What does the console say? Also check which objects observe that event, the problem is probably there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

agree with pt2ph8's comment above.

Mostly likely some object registered for a notification, then got dealloced without unregistering for a notification.  Thus the notification center is sending notifications to dead objects.

Make sure in your dealloc (or viewDidUnload for view controllers) that you are unregistering that object from all notifications.

Comment: Right, NSNotificationCenter doesn't retain observers, so it's most likely an unallocated object.